Reload BlazorWebView in a MAUI xaml page
I have a basic MAUI Blazor Hybrid app with one xaml page: MainPage.xaml and in it there is one component, the BlazorWebView
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"
    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

    <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent ComponentType="{x:Type local:Components.Routes}" Selector="#app" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>

</ContentPage>

I would like to be able to reload the BlazorWebView's content (load it as though I just arrived at the MainPage.xaml)
I tried doing
var hostPage = blazorWebView.HostPage;
blazorWebView.HostPage = null;
blazorWebView.HostPage = hostPage;

but this had no effect.
Even setting blazorWebView = null; did nothing

You can store the url when the blazorewbview rendered first time and then call the platform code to reload the url.

Does this link answer your question?

In my test, the blazorwebview's default url is https://0.0.0.0/, so you can call the platform code to reload the url. But to make the url always correct, I get it programmatically.
In the MainPage:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string url;
        public BlazorWebView view;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            view = blazorWebView;
        }
        public void Reload()
        {
#if Android
            var androidweb = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
            androidweb.LoadUrl(url);
#elif WINDOWS
            var windowweb = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
            windowweb.Source = new Uri(url);
#elif IOS
            var iosweb = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as WebKit.WKWebView;
            iosweb.LoadRequest(new Foundation.NSUrlRequest(new Uri(url)));
#endif
        }
    }

In the Home.Razor:
@code{
   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       base.OnInitialized();
#if Android
        var androidweb = (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage).view.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage).url = androidweb.Url;
#elif WINDOWS
        var windowweb = (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage).view.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
        (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage).url = windowweb.Source.ToString();
#elif IOS
        var iosweb = (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage).view.Handler.PlatformView as WebKit.WKWebView;
        (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage).url = iosweb.Url.ToString();
#endif
   }
}

And then you can call the Reload method to reload the blazor webview. Why I get the default Url in the Home.Razor is I can't get it in the MainPage's life cycle method on the windows platform.
=====================
I get another easier way to do this. You can create a new BlazorWebView and set it as the Page's Content:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Reload()
        {
            var newview = new BlazorWebView() { HostPage = "wwwroot/index.html" };
            newview.RootComponents.Add(new RootComponent() { Selector = "#app", ComponentType = typeof(Routes) });
            this.Content = newview;

        }
    }


Wow, did not think it would be so complicated and need platform specific code. Great answer

I get another easier way. You can check the update part in my answer. @adinas

That is also a good idea. I will use this actually
